# Получил ошибку django.db.utils.IntegrityError

Tags: django, база-данных, sqlite

Сайт работал как обычно, сегодня снова запустил его (сайт находится на локальном сервере), добавил модель Category, в модель Product добавил столбец description. Выполнил команду makemigrations, все прошло нормально, но когда я ввел команду migrate, вылезла ошибка **django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'store_product' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: store_product.category_id contains a value '0' that does not have a corresponding value in store_category.id.** Я понимаю, что проблема связана с связями, но не понимаю, в чем именно проблема :/

Вот код:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name = 'Имя категории')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True, related_name="customer")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 7, decimal_places = 0)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Описание', null = True)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null = True, blank = False)
    image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False, null = True, blank = False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null = True, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

Comment: проблема в миграции, не надо было ставить по умолчанию 0. откатите миграцию, измените значение по умолчанию и примените снова, и желательно чтобы связанный по FK объект существовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было удалить последнюю миграцию с папки migrations и сделать новую. Ошибка пропала :)